# jQuery stops working when quotes removed from a property in css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In jQuery docs, it is clearly mentioned quotes are optional but in my code when i remove it, error flags in `firebug` console.

> Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css({'background-color': '#ffe',
>   'border-left': '5px solid #ccc'}) and .css({backgroundColor: '#ffe',
>   borderLeft: '5px solid #ccc'}). Notice that with the DOM notation,
>   quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS
>   notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name.

Reference link: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

Let me know what I am doing wrong with the concept and what are the ways of using property/value pair in css method?

Whole code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery CSS check</title>
        <style>
        li {color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Product 1</li>
            <li>Product 2</li>
        </ul>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('li').css({color:'green',font-size:'18px'});
        });
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Error in Firebug console: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Comment: Look up what a valid property name can be in javascript. You shold enclose font-size in quotes like this "font-size"

Comment: @Yoshi Awesome!! really dont know about this .let me mix it up with other properties as well...things are now crystal clear to me regarding the convention :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya; quotes are optionnal but not for properties wich contains '-' character. So, you have to use quotes to wrap this kind of properties:

```
jQuery('li').css({color:'green','font-size':'18px'});
```

As yoshi pointed it, you can use camelcase synthax property too:

```
jQuery('li').css({color:'green',fontSize:'18px'});
```